# Why does python in VSC print out my commas in strings?

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, syntax

So this is my code:

```
name = "Nymeria"
age = 20
fav_lang = python
print("My name is", name, "and I am", age, "years old"., "My favourite programming language is", fav_lang, ".")
```

The output in Terminal: My name is Nymeria and I am 20 years old. My favourite programming language is Python

The output in VSC:
('My name is', 'Nymeria', 'and I am', 20, 'years old.', 'My favourite programming language is', 'Python')

Comment: remove the  ```.```

Comment: the point after the string "years old".,

Comment: Thank you! Though now VSC outputs this: ('My name is', 'Nymeria', 'and I am', 20, 'years old', 'My favourite programming language is', 'Python').